# Force close on trying to use default constructor

Tags: android

If I'm attempting to define a default constructor for the class which is extending an Activity I'm getting force close on application execution. Why is it so?

```
public class App extends Activity {


    App() {
              // FORCE CLOSE
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a package access constructor which is not allowed by the Android Framework,

You can create a public constructor i.e. `public App(){}` but this is really inappropriate way to initialize an activity class in Android to say the least.

Initialize all the requirements in `onCreate()` which is recommended an sensible approach.

also make sure you are defining each activity in you AndroidManifest.xml file.

with `<activity>` tag and defin `android:name` attribute at minimum.

```
<activity android:name=".SampleAppication"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You can find more information on Acitvity Lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)